# How to call Javascript code in C# Selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I am trying to access, set a variable, and call a method that is in the javascript client side on a website. I am using selenium in C#.I want to call the method below and set the `state.token = myToken`

I tried by using the javascript executor and calling the method, but nothing seemed to happen and I wasn't sure if I set the token properly. Thanks for any help.

```
const onChallengeCompleted = (ctx = {}) => {
  state.completed = true;
  state.token = ctx.token;
  invokeHook(ATTRIBUTE_EVENT_COMPLETED, new ArkHookEvent(state), ctx);
};
```

Comment: Probably depends a lot on the context of this method. Is it available on the global window object? In other words, if you open your dev console and type `onChallengeCompleted({token = myToken});` what happens? If that doesn't work, then calling it through Selenium won't work either.

Comment: Nothing comes up when that is done. I am trying to send the token to the server side instead of client side.

Comment: I am using 2captcha api for auto funcaptcha solver, but I can't seem to send the new token to server side.